# The function object and the code object relation in CPython

Tags: python, cpython

The [Include/funcobject.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Include/funcobject.h) of the **CPython** source code starts with next comment:

> Function objects and code objects should not be confused with each
>   other:
>
> Function objects are created by the execution of the 'def'
>   statement.  They reference a code object in their `__code__` attribute,
>   which is a purely syntactic object, i.e. nothing more than a compiled
>   version of some source code lines. There is one code object per source
>   code "fragment", **but each code object can be referenced by zero or
>   many function objects depending only on how many times the 'def'
>   statement in the source was executed so far.**

that I don't quite understand.

---

I write my partial understanding here. May be someone complete it.

1. **Compilation stage.**

   We have source file **Test.py**:

   ```
   def a_func():
       pass
   ```

   The interpreter parses it and creates two **code objects** - one for `Test.py` and one for `a_func`.
   The `Test.py` code object has such `co_code` field (disassembled):

   ```
     3           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object a_func at 0x7f8975622b70, file "test.py", line 3>)
                 2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a_func')
                 4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
                 6 STORE_NAME               0 (a_func)
                 8 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
                10 RETURN_VALUE
   ```

   No function object creating at this stage.
2. **Execution stage.**

   - > Function objects are created by the execution of the 'def' statement.

   When the virtual machine reach the `MAKE_FUNCTION` instruction, it creates the function object:

   ```
   typedef struct {
       PyObject_HEAD
       PyObject *func_code;        /* A code object, the __code__ attribute */
       PyObject *func_globals;     /* A dictionary (other mappings won't do) */
       PyObject *func_defaults;    /* NULL or a tuple */
       PyObject *func_kwdefaults;  /* NULL or a dict */
       PyObject *func_closure;     /* NULL or a tuple of cell objects */
       PyObject *func_doc;         /* The __doc__ attribute, can be anything */
       PyObject *func_name;        /* The __name__ attribute, a string object */
       PyObject *func_dict;        /* The __dict__ attribute, a dict or NULL */
       PyObject *func_weakreflist; /* List of weak references */
       PyObject *func_module;      /* The __module__ attribute, can be anything */
       PyObject *func_annotations; /* Annotations, a dict or NULL */
       PyObject *func_qualname;    /* The qualified name */
   } PyFunctionObject;
   ```

   - > They reference a code object in their `__code__` attribute, which is a purely syntactic object, i.e. nothing more than a compiled version of some source code lines.

   and puts the `a_func` code object into the `PyObject *func_code` field. Now, the message from the comment "The function object and the code object are not the same" is clear.

   - > There is one code object per source code "fragment", **but each code object can be referenced by zero or many function objects depending only on how many times the 'def' statement in the source was executed so far.**

   The part that I don't understand emphasized by strong font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I make a lambda factory (a good idea for scope reasons):

```
def mk_const(k):
  def const(): return k
  return const
```

then there is one code object for `mk_const` and one for `const`, but there are many function objects for the latter as calls to `mk_const` (including 0).

(It makes no difference to use a `lambda`, but it’s easier to explain with `def`.)

It can also be the result of `if`:

```
if lib.version>=4:
  def f(x): return lib.pretty(x)
else:
  def f(x): return str(x)  # fallback
```

There are two code objects here (plus the one for the module), but at most one of them gets used.